# How to show bootstrap list on google maps

Tags: html, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I have created a Google map application and used bootstrap for UI. I want to show a list on map, but cannot. 
[image]
I changed the z-index of list but did not work. I put list html code into map div but did not work. Is this a css problem?

Comment: can you share the code on jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant put anything inside the map-container, it will be overwritten by the API when you initialize the map.

You may either:

- put it somewhere else inside the document and place it via CSS on the map
- or use a it as the content of a [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

**Sample for CSS-positioning:**

place both(map-container and list-group ) in a common container, and set the position of the `container` to `relative`

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
  <ul class="list-group" style="">
    <li class="list-group-item active">item#1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">item#2</li>        
    <li class="list-group-item">item#3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS for the list-group(use `margin` to apply a padding of the list-group inside the map):

```
.list-group{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  margin:20px;
}
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/x9uRB/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/x9uRB/)

Comment: How can I place it via css? I can not do it.

Comment: I've added an example above